# Question about a substitution for the word "whose" in this context

Tags: word-choice

I wonder why the writer did not use the word "his" instead of "whose"  in the context below.

> Speaking to reporters in Taipei, Ma said that Taiwan would suffer economically if it did not sign the agreement with its biggest export destination, China. "I tell you once again, with a responsible attitude, that this is completely for the sake of Taiwan's economic future," said Ma, under **whose** rule since 2008 Taiwan has signed a series of landmark trade and economic agreements with China. ([Source](http://uk.reuters.com/article/2014/03/23/uk-taiwan-protests-idUKBREA2M02Z20140323))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, “under whose rule since 2008 Taiwan has signed a series of landmark trade and economic agreements with China” is a non-identifying relative clause.  If we used “under his rule” we would need to make it a separate sentence:  “Under his rule since 2008, Taiwan has signed a series of landmark trade and economic agreements with China.”

Here’s a simpler example of the same two structures:

> “Ma, whose father was born in China, heads the KMT party.”
>
> “Ma heads the KMT party.  His father was born in China.”

I wonder if there is some interference from Mandarin here, if that’s your native language?  Because this kind of relative clause isn’t possible in Mandarin, I believe.  Don’t confuse it with something like this:

> “The KMT president, who his father detested, was re-elected.”

That kind of relative clause (as opposed to the “whose” type) would be easily rendered in Mandarin.

Here's an example of a relative clause with "under whose":

> Football manager Alex Ferguson, under whose supervision Manchester United won 13 Premier League titles, coined the phrase “squeaky-bum time.”

Comment: Dear user2619 I know about these. Of course you helped me a lot better digesting. I can not digest the not so common use of the word "under" here. As far as my knowledge is concerned following sentences are common : That is the man whose house burned down. Solar energy is the idea whose time has come. Your examples were very similar to these two. Could you please provide some example using "under whose..." Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: @user5036 - I see what you mean.  'Under whose X plus subject of rel clause' is actually more complicated than a straight 'whose' rel clause. The example I gave could be paraphrased as 'who supervised Man U...', which might be easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

'Whose' is a relative pronoun.It marks the relative clause 'under whose rule..' A relative clause is a clause used to refer to a noun or a noun phrase.

> ..said Ma, under whose rule since 2008 Taiwan has signed a series of landmark trade and economic agreements with China.

Here, the doer of the verb 'said' and the possessor of 'the rule' are the same (Ma).
That is, whose refers to Ma. 
Relative clause are used to join two sentences.
So instead of saying:

> ..said Ma. Under his rule...,

it is easier to say:

> ..said Ma, under whose rule...

[Relative clauses](http://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/relative-clauses)